# node js утечка памяти

Tags: node.js, память, утечка-памяти, heap

Есть простое тестовой приложение:

```
var http = require('http');
var winston = require('winston');

var RequestID;
var httpurl = 'http://some_http_address';
var is_done = true;
var httpdata;

async function httpGet (url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    http.get(url, function (res) {
      switch (res.statusCode) {
        case 200:
          resolve(res);
          break;
        case 302: // redirect
          resolve(httpGet(res.headers.location));
          break;
        default:
          reject(new Error('Unexpected status-code:' + res.statusCode));
      }
    });
  });
}

async function GetData()
{
  // Get http content
  httpdata = await httpGet(httpurl, {native: true});

  /* Garbage clean */
  httpdata = null;
  is_done = true;
}

RequestID = setInterval(() => {
  global.gc();
  console.log('Memory usage:', process.memoryUsage());
 if (is_done)
 {
  is_done = false; 
  GetData();
 }
}, 3000);
```

Но вот проблема, потребляемая память постепенно растет и когда исчерпывается полностью,  приложение падает. Вызывая `process.memoryUsage()` вижу, что показатель `heapUsed` постоянно увеличивается. Если закомментировать `httpdata = await httpGet(httpurl, {native: true});`, то потребление колеблется плюс минус и все нормально.

Но в чем проблема `httpdata`, ведь после того как `httpGet` отрабатывает я очищаю `httpdata = null;`? Почему в примере пожирается вся память?

Comment: не разбирался в вашем вопросе, но `httpdata = null` не имеет отношения к освобождению ресурсов, вы просто присваиваете ссылке значение `null`

Comment: @overthesanity хм, странно, прочитал где-то в соседней теме что это выход. А как тогда освободить память в данном случае?, ведь при каждом вызове этой функции будет резервироваться все новая и новая память, а интервал подразумевает работать бесконечно долго.

Comment: Можете воспользоваться оператором `delete`.

Comment: @And не помогло, память меумолимо растет( delete в node.js работает так же как в C++?

Comment: @overthesanity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733665/how-to-prevent-memory-leaks-in-node-js в этой теме говорится "A way to force the GC to pick up data is to null your variables. How does v8 know whether it is safe to garbage collect big object when it's in an event handler? It doesn't so you need to tell it it's no longer used by setting the variable to null."

Comment: @Лев, для примера создайте простой класс и в конструкторе напишите `setTimeout(() => console.log(this), 5000)`, после этого создайте инстанс этого класса и эсайните ссылку в `null` - `let instance = new SomeClass(); instance = null`, далее вы можете воспользоваться средствами V8 и трейсить мемори лики с помощью `DebugTrackRetainingPath` (погуглите)

Comment: @overthesanity да я кажется неправильно понимал принцип работы V8 и GC, null это как бы разрешающий "флаг" для сборщика удалить объект во время автоматической сборки мусора. Пошел гуглить документацию.

Comment: Думаю что проблема решится, если избавиться от рекурсии (`resolve(httpGet(res.headers.location));` - это фактически промис промиса, и одному Ктулху известно что там тащится по ссылкам в полях его объекта).

Comment: С ходу воспроизвести проблему с этим кодом не удается (поднял рядом простейший локальный сервер, уменьшил таймаут, запустил на выходные), Использование памяти колеблется в одних и тех же пределах. Возможно, действительно, дело в обработке редиректа, это не проверял.

Comment: @yar85 спасибо за версию, но в данном случае рекурсия запустится только если сервер отдаст в заголовках код ответа 302 (этот код значит временный редирект), но я запрашиваю всегда только один и тот же адрес (причем свой же), где никаких редиректов никогда не бывает, соответственно условие никогда не выполняется и, как следствие, дело не в этом.